# A Question on Bounded linear functionals and operators

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normed space and let $T_n \in B(X,Y)$ : Bounded Linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.
I want to show that if

$\{f(T_n x)\}_n$ is bounded for any $x \in X$ and for any $f \in Y^*$,

then

$\{T_n x\}_n$ is also bounded for any $x \in X$.

How can I prove this?

Comment: $T_nx \in Y \subset Y^{**}$. So you can simply use the uniform boundedness principle on $Y^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the uniform boundedness principle. You have
$$\sup_n \{ |(f\circ T_n)(x)|_\mathbb{K}\}<\infty$$
for all $f\in Y^*$ and all $x\in X$. So
$$\sup_n\{ \|f \circ T_n\|_{X^*}\} <\infty $$
for all $f\in Y^*$. But this means
$$\sup_{n}\{\|T_n^*(f)\|_{X^*}\}<\infty$$
for all $f\in Y^*$ and from the uniform boundedness principle again:
$$\sup_n\{\|T^*_n\|_{B(Y^*,X^*)}\}<\infty$$
But that implies $\sup_n\{\|T_n(x)\|_{Y}\}<\infty.$

Comment: ok really thanks! I am wondering even I can show that $\|T_n\|$ is bounded in this situation?

Comment: Yes that is actually the implication of the last line, because $\|T_n^*\|=\|T_n\|$.